# Issue with plotting neighbors on igraph

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I identify the neighbors of a selected node but haven’t been able to plot the result. Take the following example, copied from another question:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text = "
A B
B C
C D
D E
C F
F G")

library(igraph)
graph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)
str(graph)
#IGRAPH DN-- 7 6 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] A->B B->C C->D D->E C->F F->G
```

I identify the neighbors of "D" with:

```
neighborsD <- neighbors(graph, "D")
```

But when I instruct R to plot "neighborsD"...

```
plot(neighborsD)
```

... I get a chart instead of a sociogram, and when I try to tkplot it I get the error "not a graph object". So two questions:

1) How do I plot the network around, say, "D"?

2) How do I plot “D”, its neighbors, and the neighbors of the neighbors (two steps from "D"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ego()` function to find nodes that are a certain distance away from a a node. And then use `induced_subgraph` to subset your main graph. For example, the does that are 1 step away are

```
plot(induced_subgraph(graph, ego(graph, 1, "D")[[1]]))
```

[image]

and those that are two steps away are

```
plot(induced_subgraph(graph, ego(graph, 2, "D")[[1]]))
```

[image]